# Question about the polynomial grade of a finitely generated ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (not necessary Noetherian), $Q$ its total ring of fractions, and $I$ a finitely generated ideal of $R$ such that $\forall$ $a \in I$ we have $(a:_R I) = a$. My question is how to prove that this implies $(R:_Q I) = I$ (equivalently $Gr_RI\ge 2$, with $Gr_R$ is the polynomial grade as defined in the Chapter 5, page 149, of the book *Finite Free Resolutions* by D. G. Northcott.)

Comment: I may have been negligent in the statement of the question. the element $a$ should be neither zero nor a divisor of zero. The original question (which is not really a question but a lemma) states that the following two statements are equivalent:
1- $(a:_R I) = a$ for some a $\in I -Z(R)$
2- $(R:_K I) = R$

Comment: Z(R) : the set of zero divisor of R;
K = the total quotient ring of R.

Comment: You want to prove the following: if $I\subseteq Z_R(R/(a))$ then there is $\hat r\in R/(a)$, $\hat r\ne0$ such that $I\hat r=0$, and I can't see how can you do this unless $R$ is noetherian.

Comment: According to lemma 3.1 of the article "LCM-stableness in ring extensions" by Hirohumi UDA it is true for all finitely generated ideal, he said that the result is easy so the proof is omitted.I try to understand the lemma, and it does not seem to me that easy.

Comment: That lemma is not exactly what you asked here. Better say where you were stuck on that proof.

Comment: how to proof that (4) is equivalent to (5) in the lemma ?

Comment: Actually I can prove (3) equivalent to (5) :)

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can give me some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $Q$ its total ring of fractions, and $I\subset R$ an ideal (containing a non-zero divisor). Then $(a:I)=(a)$ for each $a\in I-Z(R)$ iff $(R:_QI)=R$.

Let $x=u/v\in Q$ such that $xI\subset R$. Then $uI\subset (v)$. Since $v\in R-Z(R)$, and $I$ contains a non-zero divisor, say $b$, we have $bv\in I-Z(R)$. From $uI\subset (v)$ we get $buI\subset (bv)$, hence $bu\in(bv:I)=(bv)$. It follows $u\in (v)$, that is, $x\in R$.

Conversely, let $r\in (a:I)$. We get $rI\subset (a)$, hence $(r/a)I\subset R$. Then $r/a\in R$, so $r\in (a)$.